# Running Java/Minecraft with the Nvidia GPU

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, java, minecraft

I have ripped the web up trying to figure this out. Bumblebee hasn't helped. I want to run Minecraft on the Nvidia GPU in my laptop. As far as I can tell, Ubuntu default runs it with Intel because Minecraft runs inside of Java, which, obviously, is not generally GPU intensive. I'm using Bionic Beaver, and the optirun command is broken. It throws an error that the nvidia-fallback.service is disabled, but trying to enable it reveals that the file doesn't exist. As far as I can tell, this is a Bionic Beaver problem. The primusrun command seems to work, but now I can't make it run Minecraft specifically. I feel like the problem could be fixed with an Nvidia application profile for Java runtime, but I don't understand the documentation on Nvidia's website. If someone can just post a rule key that forces an application to use Nvidia (and actually works; I found one, but it's "not recognized"), that would be great.

specs:
Lenovo y520 laptop
i5 CPU
Intel 620 HD/Nvidia geforce 1050 ti
8 gb ram
Ubuntu 18.04

if I missed any specs, please tell me, I'm new to posting questions.

Comment: As this is the second result on DuckDuckGo in case you're wondering how to do this on AMD please check out my answer to [AMD-AMD Switchable GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117612/amd-amd-switchable-gpu).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## First,

Inside your 'NVIDIA X Server Settings' window, underneath a drop-down menu called something like "GPU 0 (GeForce GTX .....)" there is an option for creating Application Profiles appropriately titled such. Click it.

[Creating Application Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl8Sl.png)

Once in this window, you should see **two tabs**. One called **Rules**, and the other called **Profiles**. *Click the **Profiles** tab* and then click the **green plus button just beneath** it to add a new profile.**Name this profile what you want** (something memorable) and add all listed settings (They're what Minecraft actually needs and avoids redundancies):

- GLAllowFXAAUsage        = **true**
- GLGSyncAllowed          = **true**
- GLShaderDiskCache       = **true**
- GLThreadedOptimizations = **true**
- GLSyncToVblank          = **true**

Select the setting from the drop-down menu under the "Source File" entry and click the green plus button to add it to the list.

Source File should be left alone. This is the location where these profile settings are saved. Ubuntu generates this location for you by default.* **DO NOT** *edit this*.

Once your list is complete and looks like mine, click the **green plus button at the bottom of the window** to save the current profile.

[Adding New Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5TOA.png)

## Next,

We need to add rules to this profile such as, which process ID's can utilize it's power and if this rule applies to all programs that use the GPU.

Click the **rules** tab and add a new rule using the **green plus button**.
In a section of this window called **Rule Pattern** there's a drop-down menu and a text entry. In the drop-down menu select **Always Applies** and in the text entry field type **Java**.

In a section called **Rule Profile** there should be a drop-down menu. Click on that and select the Profile you just created. A list of all the NVIDIA GL settings you added should appear in the list space below. If this is true for you click the **green plus button** at the bottom of the window to save.

[Adding New Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRWj.png)

## Then,

If you have followed all these steps correctly your NVIDIA x Server Settings Application Profiles window on **Rules** tab should look something like this:

```
| Priority  | Pattern    | Profile Settings
--------------------------------------------
| 1         | [true]Java | GLAllowFXAAUsage=true,GL...
```

[Completed Application Profile Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X7F9.png)

## Lastly,

Save the new configuration you just created by clicking the **disk icon with the green down arrow**.

You may now close the NVIDIA Server Settings window, start Minecraft and Enjoy. If you have any questions pertaining to this thread or my post, or if you have any issues with this configuration please let me know. *Use my profile link.*

---

EXTRAS

In the rules tab, you can create a new rule with the *Always Applies* feature to the process ID of a running instance of Minecraft. Use the terminal and type

```
ps -U root -u root -N
```

locate a process called **Java**.
*Looks like this*:

```
4307 tty1     01:44:08 java
```

Copy the PID number (in my case: 4307) and use that in the text entry labeled "Matches this String". Save and exit.

**NOTE:** This doesn't work all the time and has to be updated frequently because the PID changes.

Comment: Very good information! Do you know how enable SLI?

Comment: This appears to be broken for me. None of the settings in the profile configuration appear to match any valid keys.

Answer (score 3):

I've done it! I've found it! I found a hack that works!

Make a script at any desired location. Save the file path for later. I personally put mine at `~/.minecraft/launch.sh`. Copy and paste the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/prime-run /usr/bin/java "$@"
```

Your `java` or `prime-run` executables may be found somewhere else. To find them, simply type these into your terminal

```sh
which java
which prime-run
```

`prime-run` is used by Nvidia to launch any program using the GPU. I installed `prime-run` by installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers. See instructions by your Linux distro on how to install them.

The `$@` [variable](https://www.poftut.com/how-to-pass-and-parse-linux-bash-script-arguments-and-parameters/) contains all the arguments passed to the script.

Don't forget to make the script executable!

```bsh
chmod +x ~/.minecraft/launch.sh
```

---

Open up the Minecraft launcher, and go to the `Installations` tab. You'll have to do this with each installation, which is fine for me since I usually play on the latest Fabric release.

[image: Installations Tab, Hovering over "edit."]

Once you've hit `Edit`, you'll want to hit the `MORE OPTIONS` submenu at the bottom, and change the Java executable path.

[image: The "more options" submenu, highlighting "Java Executable"]

Find the script from above, and set it as the new "executable." Load up the game, join a world, press F3 and double check that it's using your Nvidia GPU!

Without the GPU:
[image]
With the GPU:
[image: F3 debug menu, showcasing the GPU being used.]
(To notice the differences, look at the top right for the hardware list.)

---

This is more of a hack than anything, but it works and now I can play modded and stream without my laptop dying on me. I hope this helps everyone well.

EDIT: Don't place the script in the `~/.minecraft/launcher/launch.sh` directory. Whenever the launcher updates, it'll be removed. Placing it outside the directory, over in `~/.minecraft/launch.sh` works fine.

EDIT 2: If you ever get stuck on the "Finalizing" stage when launching, it's because the `launch.sh` script isn't executable! Make sure to add the executable bit onto the file.

EDIT 3: Make sure the Bash arguments are quoted! If they aren't quoted, then this means that not all arguments will be respected, which could lead to lower or higher ram usage than specified.

Comment: Adding on to Lunar's answer, I'd like to point out that if the `prime-run` doesn't work, replace it with `switcherooctl launch`. That's what worked for me.

Comment: @HackerDaGreat57, could you specify which distro you're on?

Answer (score 3):

0. Download and install the Minecraft launcher. The official site has a `.deb` package, so all you need is to download it, go to its directory and execute `sudo apt install ./Minecraft.deb`.
1. Install Nvidia's driver. You can use `nvidia-detect` to find out which one you should install. It will probably be simply `sudo apt install nvidia-driver`.
2. Reboot (perhaps not needed).
3. Run Minecraft with

   ```
   __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia minecraft-launcher
   ```

   As described in https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts%2F436-running-application-on-nvidia.html.

Answer (score 2):

prime-run is deprecated. The answer which worked for me was

`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia minecraft-launcher`

Comment: `prime-run` is a bash script which merely sets environment variables. Additionally you're missing the `__VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only` environment variable for Vulkan.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 hours on the problem, for everyone using pop os, you can right click the app in the "show applications" window and there is an option to run the launcher with "discrete graphics card", fixing the isue for me

Answer (score 0):

I entered this in terminal and it launched with 60 fps:

```
sudo DRI_PRIME=1 java -jar /bin/TLauncher-2.75.jar
```

`/bin/TLauncher-2.75.jar` is my location for Java launcher.

Answer (score 0):

install `nvidia-prime` and run the launcher with `prime-run java -jar ./launchersname.jar`