# How do I run Minecraft on Nvidia GPU?

Tags: minecraft, hybrid-graphics

[Running Java/Minecraft with the Nvidia GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108043/running-java-minecraft-with-the-nvidia-gpu) did not help me.

How can I force it to run on the Nvidia graphics card?

What I tried:

- Obviously everything in [Running Java/Minecraft with the Nvidia GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108043/running-java-minecraft-with-the-nvidia-gpu)
- Trying to solve problems that arose from above.
- Trying to solve problems that arose from above.
- Asking random people.
- Finally breaking Ubuntu while trying to fix.

Edit:

Fixed it!
What I needed was an Nvidia driver and simple right-click and "Start With Dedicated Graphics Card" button.