# custom profile Nvidia profile gone wrong and doesn't allow me to log in as "ubuntu on wayland"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, minecraft

I had a problem to make Minecraft use the GPU instead of the CPU

i got this fix -i don't know if it's working or not btw- [FIX](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177418/1672768)

But it messed up my logging as Ubuntu on wayland after typing the pass it loops again and i rewrite my pass again over and over so i had to change to log in normally to Ubuntu

Btw if anyone knows active way to make minecraft use the GPU and stop eating my 16GB ram i'll be thankful to you

my device specs

> Acer Nitro AN515-52

> Memory 16.0 GiB

> CPU Intel® Core™ i7-8750H × 12

> GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 mobile

> OS Ubuntu 23.04 *NOTE* it was all the same from  V22.04 to the current one

> OS Type 64-bit

**Any farther info required please let me know**